# What is this plant with long thin leaves?

Tags: identification, weeds

Found these coming up quickly in my yard and not sure what they are. I live in Northeast Ohio. Stem starts out red then turns green.

[image]

Comment: Few more closeup pictures of the leaves, stem etc along with the location would help..

Comment: Welcome! Please see the tag info for [tag:identification]. We need reasonably clear photos and a bit of description, e.g. where in the world the plants are. Please take the [tour], browse through the [help], especially [ask], then [edit] your post with more details that help us help you.

Comment: I would venture to suggest emerging peony stems.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be [peony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peony), at a glance. Depending on how happy it is or isn't you might get some impressive flowers, or just foliage. Red start going green and general shape look correct based on mine. They will generally benefit from some support, especially if they are happy enough to bud and flower. Also, don't go nuts killing harmless (perhaps even helpful) ants on the buds.