# Perennial plant with red stem and leaves

Tags: identification

Anyone know what plant this is? I got a new home and killed the plants on the side yard and laid mulch. This plant is coming up again  this year and I'm thinking if it's a nice flowering bush I'll leave it to grow this year[image: its growing red stems and kinda creepy red leaves]

Comment: Did you lay the rock mulch on top of fabric?

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/62178/6806 might as well see https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/62249/6806 if you're new to peonies, too.

Answer (score 5):

That's almost certainly a peony; it's pretty small and was probably being out-competed by the plants you killed, so it may not flower this year. Also, if this area is in full shade you'll want to move it this Octover.